# Renaming file in java

Tags: java, file

I tried to rename a file, using code I found here:

```
File newFile = new File(oldFile.getParent(), "new-file-name.txt");
Files.move(oldFile, newFile);
```

Now, what I did was this:

```
  private void stFiles() {
    System.out.println("sorting");
    File f = new File (getName());
    name = getName() + counter.toString();
    System.out.println(f.getName());
    File newFile = new File(f.getParent(), getName()+ ".jpg");
    try {
        Files.move(f, newFile);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("made file");
    }
    counter +=1;
}
```

Now, I get the "made file" print, Which means there is an IO-Exception. The Stack Trace, however, is not readable.

What can be the reason for this?

Comment: `System.out.println("made file");` is in your `Exception` handler...meaning something unexpected went wrong.  Try adding `ex.printStackTrace();` under the `System.out.println` line...

Comment: Check the message of the IOException you are receiving (either by debugging or by changing your `System.out.println` to `ex.printStackTrace()`. That will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Why not use `File.renameTo()`?

Comment: Realized that probably about the Moment you wrote, sorry.... I am not using rename because in another Thread here someone said it was not safe on all operating Systems.

Comment: @newnewbie It depends on how you intend to use it I would say. From JavaDoc: `Many aspects of the behavior of this method are inherently platform-dependent: The rename operation might not be able to move a file from one filesystem to another, it might not be atomic, and it might not succeed if a file with the destination abstract pathname already exists. The return value should always be checked to make sure that the rename operation was successful.` But I get your point.

Comment: What is "name" variable for?, did you forget to use it anywhere?

Comment: No, but it DOES work now - I DID forget to append the .jpg.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the renameTo method which already exists in File object as shown below:

```
File myOriginalFile=new File("myOriginalFile.txt");
    File myChangedFile=new File("myChangedFile.txt");



    if(myOriginalFile.renameTo(myChangedFile)){
        System.out.println("Rename operation succesful");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Rename operation failed");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Java allows you to rename a file by using the renameTo(File file) method which is there in the java.io.File class.

First, obtain a reference to the file that you want to rename. Second, invoke the renameTo() method on that reference using a File argument.
 Suppose you have a file named file1.txt and you want to rename it file2.txt.

The code lines below show how it's done:

```
//Obtain the reference of the existing file
File oldFile = new File("file1.txt"); 

//Now invoke the renameTo() method on the reference, oldFile in this case
oldFile.renameTo(new File("file2.txt"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If your file is on a Windows share, you may face issues using the `File.renameTo()` method.

A more robust solution is to use Apache Commons IO [FileUtils.moveFile()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#moveFile%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29)

Comment: Will that problem also apply to what I did?

Comment: I checked on a windows system yesterday -apparently without any problems